# I need advice how to improve graphics

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I have file with table containing 23 millions records the following form {atomName, x, y, z, transparence}. For solutions I decided to use OpenGL.

My task to render it. In first iteration, I used block "glBegin/glEnd" and have drawed every atom as point some color. This solution worked. But I got 0.002 fps.

Then i tried using VBO. I formed three buffers: vertex, color and indexes. This solution worked. I got 60 fps, but i have not comfortable binding buffers and i am drawing points, not spheres.

Then i read about VAO, which can simplify binding buffers. Ok, it is worked. I got comfortable binding.

Now i want to draw spheres, not points. I thought, to form relative to each point of the set of vertices on which it will be possible to build a sphere (with some accuracy). But if i have 23 million vertices, i must calculate yet ~12 or more vertices relaty every point. 23 000 000 * 4 (float) = 1 Gb data, perhaps it not good solution.

What is the best next move i should do?  I can not fully understand, applicable shaders in this task or exist other ways.

Comment: I think Textured point sprites might work as your sphere are same from each angle of view.

Comment: You means that i should output sprite of sphere in every point(x,y,z)?

Comment: Textured point sprites are basically points which have texture. So it is (probably) what you have done already but you slap texture on top of it. this will give you the more spherical look for your atoms. Take look here http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=770639&seqNum=7. Or just google `Textured point sprites` to get what I mean.

Comment: Take look here, you might find it useful in order to understand the technique: http://fullonsoftware.co.uk/snippets/content/OpenGL_-_Particle_System_Tutorial_-_Blending_-_PointSprites.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## About your drawing process

> My task to render it. In first iteration, I used block "glBegin/glEnd" and have drawed every atom as point some color. This solution worked. But I got 0.002 fps.

Think about it: For every of your 23 million records you make at least one function call directly (glVertex) and probably several function calls implicitly by that. Even worse, glVertex likely causes a context switch. What this means is, that your CPU hits several speed bumps for every vertex it has to processes. A top notch CPU these days has a clock rate of about 3 GHz and a pipeline length in the order of 10 instructions. When you make a context switch that pipeline gets stalled, in the worst case it then takes one pipeline length to actually process one single instruction. Lets consider that you have to perform at least 1000 instructions for processing a single glVertex call (which is actually a rather optimistic estimation). That alone means, that you're limited to process at most 3 million vertices per second. So at 23 million vertices that's already less than one FPS then.

But you also got context switches in there, which add a further penality. And probably a lot of branching which create further pipeline flushes.

And that's just the glVertex call. You also have colors in there.

*And you wonder that immediate mode is slow?*

Of course it's slow. Using the Immediate Mode has been discouraged for well over 15 years. Vertex Arrays are available since OpenGL-1.1.

> This solution worked. I got 60 fps,

Yes, because all the data resides on the GPU's own memory now. GPUs are massively parallel and optimized to crunch this kind of data and doing the operations they do.

> but i have not comfortable binding buffers

Well, OpenGL is not a high level scene graph library. It's a mid to low level drawing API. You use it like a sophisticated pencil to draw on a digital canvas.

> Then i read about VAO

Well, VAOs are meant to coalesce buffer objects that belong together so it makes sense using them.

> Now i want to draw spheres, not points.

You have two options:

- Using point sprite textures. This means that your points will get area when drawn, and that area gets a texture applied. I think this is the best method for you. Given the right shader you can even give your point sprite the right kind of depth values, so that your "spheres" will actually intersect like spheres in the depth buffer.
- The other option is using instancing a single sphere geometry, using your atom records as control data for the instancing process. This would then process real sphere geometry. However I fear that implementing an instanced drawing process might be a bit too advanced for your skill level at the moment.

## About drawing 23 million points

Seriously what kind of display do you have available, that you can draw 23 million, distinguishable points? Your typical computer screen will have some about 2000×1500 points. The highest resolution displays you can buy these days have about 4k×2.5k pixels, i.e. 10 million individual pixels. Let's assume your atoms are evenly distributed in a plane: At 23 million atoms to draw each pixel will get several times overdrawn. You simply can't display 23 million individual atoms that way. Another way to look at this is, that the display's pixel grid implies a spatial sampling and you can't reproduce anything smaller than twice the average sampling distance (sampling theorem).

So it absolutely makes sense to draw only a subset of the data, namely the subset that's actually in view. Also if you're zoomed very far out (i.e. you have the full dataset in view) it makes sense to coalesce atoms closeby.

It definitely makes sense to sort your data into a spatial subdivision structure. In your case I think an octree would be a good choice.